# Override Amasty template

Tags: magento2, template, template-override

New to magento, I'm trying to override `vendor/Amasty/Promo/view/frontend/templates/notification.phtml` called in `vendor/Amasty/Promo/view/frontend/layout/default.xml`

So I've added the file in this location`design/frontend/MYTHEME/default/Amasty_Promo/templates/notification.phtml`

The override is still not working. Any ideas ?

EDIT

default.xml

```
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="main.content">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Messages" name="messages" as="messages" template="Magento_Theme::messages.phtml" before="-"/>
        <block class="Amasty\Promo\Block\Notification" name="amasty.promo.notification" before="-"/>
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

What version are you using?

By a chance I got the module but I don't see any instructions in the file you mentioned.

```
vendor/Amasty/Promo/view/frontend/layout/default.xml
```

=

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * @author Amasty Team
 * @copyright Copyright (c) 2019 Amasty (https://www.amasty.com)
 * @package Amasty_Promo
 */
-->

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <!-- TODO: Delete this file after 16.01.2020 -->
</page>
```

Your syntax is right, did you clear the cache? or turned it off for develpoment?

Oh and remember to turn on the developer mode!

```
bin/magento cache:flush
```

Comment: I've been adding the default xml in the message.

Comment: Did you turn on your new design ?

Comment: it's not a new one so I guess yes^^ I'm just trying to an the override into this existing design

Comment: @Kurano did you manage to fix the problem ?